# Add custom product option to woocommerce orders list

Tags: woocommerce, admin

I am using the "custom product options" plugin and created a datepicker for customers to choose a requested ship date. I need to create a column on my orders admin page for their selection so I do not have to go into the order to find the date. I have found a few different threads that are similar but they don't really apply to my exact situation. Would someone be able to provide some help on this? Apologies for a lack of detail that is getting me downvotes, but If I knew what I needed I wouldn't be here asking what to do. I am a novice, cut me a little slack. Datepicker can be seen here.

https://chrish148.sg-host.com/product/butterscotch-oatmeal-copy/

current layout looks like this.
[current layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1H2b6.png)

Comment: Dosn't the plugin already do that? Can you give some more information? Like how does the admin page look right now and give more information about what you are really looking for?

Comment: The admin order page is how it is out of the box. There is a dropdown to change the menu items that are there by default, but what i am trying to ass is the field that is created by using the date picker on each product page. Can be seen here. https://chrish148.sg-host.com/product/butterscotch-oatmeal-copy/  When the customer selects the date it shows up inside the order properly, but I need the date to show up as a column in the orders list.

Comment: edited original post with image and link to date picker.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I used for one of my WooCommerce sites to get order-colors:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns','shopOrder',10 );
function shopOrder($columns)
{
    $columns['custom_color_column'] = "Färger";
    return $columns;    
}

add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'populateShopOrder' );
function populateShopOrder( $column ) {
    global $the_order, $post;

    if( $column == 'custom_color_column' ) {
        global $post, $the_order;

        if ( empty( $the_order ) || $the_order->get_id() !== $post->ID ) {
            $the_order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
        }

        if ( empty( $the_order ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $items = $the_order->get_items();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
          // load meta data - product attributes
          foreach ($item->get_meta_data() as $metaData) {
            $attribute = $metaData->get_data();
            // attribute value
            $value = $attribute['value'];
            
            if($value != null && $attribute['key'] == "pa_farg"){
                echo "- " . $value;
                if(count($items) > 1) echo "<br>";
            }
            else return;
          }
        }

    }

}
```

However this might not be the exakt case for you. Since I do not know the exact plugin that you are using I can not know for sure.

However it should be close.
If you can figure out the attribute names then you could switch it from "fa_farg" to that, or you could link the plugin thet you are using and I will take a look at it.